# clang insists on compiling uncalled functions

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, clang++

Moving from using Intel compiler & VC to Apple clang 12.0.

In my code there are functions that are never called for a certain project (but needed when included in other projects). Clang insists on compiling the uncalled functions and detects errors, where Intel and VC simply skipped compilation.

These are errors that are tricky to fix for that certain project.

Is there a Clang flag that means "Don't compile if not called"?

**EDIT**: example:

```
template <class T> class A
{
public:
    void foo() { garbage }; // <--- syntax error
};

int main() {
    A<int> my_obj;
    //my_obj.foo(); // <--- when unremarked, will fail all compilers
}
```

[Compiler Explorer demo: Intel vs. Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/9eG7Pv)

Intel and VC compilers are relaxed until the call to foo() enters the scene.

Comment: How do you expect clang to know you don't call that function in another compilation unit?

Comment: Can you add an example? (See compiler-explorer.com if you want to run multiple compilers on the same code)

Comment: This really needs a [mcve].  Compilers do not differ regarding _when to compile a fnuction_.

Comment: I doubt your claims about Intel's and Microsoft's compilers, but surely this can be easily fixed by moving the definitions of the functions to files that you don't compile?

Comment: I am certain you refer to template functions that weren't called for. Otherwise that's just wrong. Clang and GCC unlike MSVC perform static pre-compilation of templates and require them to compile which is also a general requirement of the C++ standart.

Comment: @DrewDormann I've recently introduced clang as 2nd compiler next to MSVC, trust me, MSVC does differ when compiling (templated) functions and does a lot of other ugly stuff.

Comment: @ALX23z correct... this is a template function that isn't (and shouldn't) be used in this project. Clang still compiles where the other compilers don't. I'll try and produce a minimal reproduction.

Comment: @gil_mo Is it anything like the three examples here: https://godbolt.org/z/T6s8KG (Which MSVC is wrong to allow, since it doesn't do two phase compilation like it is supposed to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clang has a mode in which is tries to behave as if it's MSVC. This was introduced as part clang-cl, the driver for clang that accepts a lot of the same arguments as MSVC. You can find some information about it on the [user manual](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#clang-cl) and the [MSVC compatibility](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MSVCCompatibility.html) pages.

Long story short, there is an option `-fdelayed-template-parsing` in clang that takes over the faulty behavior of the templates. As far as I'm aware, this ain't a 100% match, however, it is good enough.

If we add this to the example of Artyer, it compiles the code, see [compiler-explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/as15E5).

From my experience of adding clang as 2nd compiler next to MSVC (it was still both on Windows using clang-cl, I didn't have to deal with the complexity of multiple OS and/or STL), I want to recommend to you to take this option as a temporary thing to get things working. Take your time removing this, as it will help making your code more maintainable.

**EDIT:** If you want to know more about why the compilation error is the right thing to do, you can lookup the term `2 phase lookup`. You can find the announcement of it's introduction in the MSVC compiler here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/two-phase-name-lookup-support-comes-to-msvc/

From what I can see online, the intel compiler ain't doing 2 phase lookup either, or at least not the reporting of the errors.

Comment: Note that this seems to only affect templates - not regular functions.

Comment: Please see my EDIT. Any explanation why Intel accepts this code? What is the "By the C++ book" way - fail or no fail?

Comment: I'll do the edit later, the C++ way is to fail on this code. I don't have experience with Intel compiler so can't give info about that, though, I assume it does the same broken thing as MSVC